# Calling parent method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some Factory:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    property1: "str",
    property2: "str",
    property3: "str",
    func: function() {/*....*/},
    childObj:{
      prop1: "str",
      prop2: "str",
      childFunc: function() {
         //....;
         func();    
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Can I call parent factory method inside child method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can I call parent method inside child method inside Angularjs factory?

As you defined factory - **no**

```
app.factory('myFactory', function(){
   return{
    property1:"str",
    property2:"str",
    property3:"str",
    func:function(){
      return "fess";
    },
    childObj:{
       prop1:"str",
       prop2:"str",
       childFunc:function(){
          return func();    // here you will get error: func() is undefined
       }
    }
  }
 })
```

---

However this will work, when we create `factory` var:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function(){
   var factory = {
    property1:"str",
    property2:"str",
    property3:"str",
    func:function(){
      return "fess";
    },
    childObj:{
       prop1:"str",
       prop2:"str",
       childFunc:function(){
          return factory.func();    // <-- OK
       }
    }
  };

  return factory;
 })
```

Call:

```
console.log(myFactory.childObj.childFunc()); // fess
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OAlvs87pU5wFXRM7RFbb?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank u, I will do like you say)